# JavaScript : Always Redirect To HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, web

So i have this website and i want it always redirect to HTTPS when anybody browse it on the web. I want to use JavaScript for it

Is this code correct?

```
if(window.location.protocol != "https:") {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    window.location.replace("https" + currentURL.substring(4));
}
```

I'm still a noob. Help me please :)

Comment: Where do you host this website? IIS?

Comment: Why not a 301 redirect ? It can be memorized by the Browser so it's more secure. And if you use the powerful HSTS header, it will be even more secure! If you do that only to trick search engine, you should know they execute js...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
    var mainurl = window.location.href.substr(5);
    window.location = "https:" + mainurl;
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: he already knows what he is doing its just that his code dint work as expected so I said try this there is nothinng much to explain there